# Query the most recent record based on an ID

Tags: sql, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group

I have a table as below. The set of records in the image have the same "name" and "id". I want to retrieve the most recent record from this dataset using "ID" as a factor, so Max(ID). My goal is to report the most recent "size". How do I go about doing this? I don't want to use a where condition using "Workbook_id" because there are many other records in the dataset with duplicate names.

[image]

Comment: See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/greatest-n-per-group+postgresql

Comment: Please read http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557 and the accepted answer

Comment: There is **no** *most recent*. Why is there no Primary Key defined for this table?

Comment: *have the same "name" and "id"* - your screen shot shows a different value in the id column for every row

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bit of a spitball, but I believe this is what you're seeking:

```
with workbookz as (
  select
    w.*,
    max (w.id) over (partition by w.workbook_id) as max_id
  from workbooks w
)
select
  id, workbook_id, name, repository_url, size, revision
from workbookz
where id = max_id
```

Obviously, if your table isn't named `workbooks` change that to whatever is appropriate.